# Calculating Stock Ending Time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

**Table:** `StoreItems`

[image]

**Table:** `StockInOutType`

[image]

**Table:** `Store`

[image]

I want to calculate stock entry time and ending time.

My query

```
SELECT  
    ItemName, DateTime [Entry Time], Qty 
FROM 
    Store 
JOIN
    StockInOutType ON Store.StockInOutType = StockInOutType.Id
JOIN
    StoreItems ON Store.ItemID = StoreItems.ItemID
WHERE 
    Store.StockInOutType = 4 
    AND StoreItems.ItemID = 25 
    AND SessionID = 735721
```

`StockInOuttype` 4 and 6 are not sale.

**Data** (`Store` table)

[image]

**Required Output:**

```
    ItemName      EntryTime              Quantity            EndingTime
Chicken Biryani   2015-09-03 10:16:09       1              2015-09-03 10:18:20
Chicken Biryani   2015-09-03 10:21:26       10             2015-09-03 10:22:17
Chicken Biryani   2015-09-03 10:26:25       15             2015-09-03 10:57:18
Chicken Biryani   2015-09-03 10:26:57       10                    null
```

Comment: Yes .... and? Is the output "wrong" / not what you expected? Then you'll need to tell us what you expected / what you need. Or what else **is really** your question??

Comment: Thats the required output

Comment: You need to clarify few things in your question: **1)** What is the input? **2)**  What is your approach? **3)** What is the output of your query/or your approach? **4)** and What is the expected output?

Comment: I think your `Store` table schema missing linking between in entry and out entry. I mean how can u say table id x which has entry time and link with out time to id y. Rather update table schema and add `out time` in it perhaps u dont need to enter 2 different entries for same item inventory(in and out).

Comment: With reference to above comment: for instance lets say Item Name `Chicken Biryani` with Qty `15` and `EntryTime` - `2015-09-03 10:56:25` (Check in que you mention wrong time) so this entry how related to row id `29` which has `EndingTime`?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Chicken Biryani with Qty 15 and EntryTime - 2015-09-03 10:56:25 end on  2015-09-03 10:57:18  (row 30).     (From id 15 to 30 15 biryani sold in between another stock of 10 biryani came in but its not open untill previous stock ended )

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Its FIFO, `15` came first, so must be finished first. Then next pack will be consumed. So `QTY 15` ends on `row #` 30. Then `QTY 10` will start to be consumed.

Answer (score 2):

The big question is what you want to happen if there is a 'Purchased' activity while there is still available stock.  Since you don't have a link from a 'Sale' to the stock this behaviour is hard to track.  Assuming this doesn't happen/you don't care about this case, the solution is to simply to choose the next stocking as a bookend as follows

```
SELECT ItemName, 
    DateTime AS [Entry Time], 
    Qty, 
    CASE WHEN LEAD(Store.DateTime) OVER (ORDER BY Store.DateTime) IS NOT NULL 
         THEN (SELECT MAX(DateTime) 
               FROM Store s2 
               WHERE s2.StockInOutType = 2 AND 
                     s2.DateTime < LEAD(Store.DateTime) OVER (ORDER BY Store.DateTime)) 
    ELSE NULL END AS EndingTime
FROM 
    Store 
WHERE 
    Store.StockInOutType = 4 
AND Store.ItemID = 25 
ORDER BY DateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the turnover of inventory in a FIFO pattern by calculating a serial number for the start and exit points of each purchase transaction.

This can be done in SQL Server by using a running total (`SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY TransactionDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`)

Example ([SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf8ed/1)):

```sql
-- Calculate serials for the orders and inventory receipts
-- put them in temp tables to make them easier to work with.  This could
-- also be done with a view or a CTE
CREATE TABLE #Orders (
  TxnID INT NOT NULL,
  TxnDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  ItemID INT NOT NULL,
  Qty INT NOT NULL,
  ConsumptionStartSerial INT,
  ConsumptionEndSerial INT
);

INSERT INTO #Orders (TxnID, TxnDate, ItemID, Qty, ConsumptionStartSerial, ConsumptionEndSerial)
SELECT TxnID, TxnDate, ItemID, Qty, ConsumptionEndSerial - Qty as ConsumptionStartSerial, ConsumptionEndSerial
FROM (
    SELECT TxnID, TxnDate, ItemID, ChangeQty * -1 as Qty,
      SUM(ChangeQty) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY TxnID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) * -1 as ConsumptionEndSerial
    FROM ItemTransactions
    WHERE ChangeQty < 0
) as inr;
SELECT * FROM #Orders;

CREATE TABLE #InventoryReceipts (
  TxnID INT NOT NULL,
  ItemID INT NOT NULL,
  Qty INT NOT NULL,
  StockStartSerial INT,
  StockEndSerial INT
);

INSERT INTO #InventoryReceipts (TxnID, ItemID, Qty, StockStartSerial, StockEndSerial)
SELECT TxnID, ItemID, Qty, StockEndSerial - Qty as StockStartSerial, StockEndSerial
FROM (
    SELECT TxnID, ItemID, ChangeQty as Qty,
      SUM(ChangeQty) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY TxnID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as StockEndSerial
    FROM ItemTransactions
    WHERE ChangeQty > 0
) as inr;
SELECT * FROM #InventoryReceipts;

-- Stock turnover
--  Find the first and last order for each inventory receipt
--  Calculate the days on shelf based off of the first and last
--  order which uses the product
SELECT inr.TxnID as StockTxn, txn.TxnDate, txn.[Description], inr.ItemID, inr.Qty, i.Name, 
    inr.StockOpenedTxnID, inr.StockFinishedTxnID,
    DATEDIFF(day, txn.TxnDate, oStart.TxnDate) as DaysToOpen,
    DATEDIFF(day, txn.TxnDate, oEnd.TxnDate) as DaysToConsumed
FROM (
    SELECT ir.TxnID, ir.ItemID, ir.Qty, MAX(oStart.TxnID) as StockOpenedTxnID, MIN(oEnd.TxnID) as StockFinishedTxnID
    FROM #InventoryReceipts ir
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Orders oStart on ir.ItemID = oStart.ItemID and ir.StockStartSerial >= oStart.ConsumptionStartSerial
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Orders oEnd on ir.ItemID = oEnd.ItemID and ir.StockEndSerial < oEnd.ConsumptionEndSerial
    GROUP BY ir.TxnID, ir.ItemID, ir.Qty
) as inr
INNER JOIN Items i on inr.ItemID = i.ItemID
INNER JOIN ItemTransactions txn on inr.TxnID = txn.TxnID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Orders oStart ON inr.StockOpenedTxnID = oStart.TxnID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Orders oEnd ON inr.StockFinishedTxnID = oEnd.TxnID

DROP TABLE #InventoryReceipts;
DROP TABLE #Orders;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf8ed/1/8)**:

```
| StockTxn |                   TxnDate |               Description | ItemID | Qty |    Name | StockOpenedTxnID | StockFinishedTxnID | DaysToOpen | DaysToConsumed |
|----------|---------------------------|---------------------------|--------|-----|---------|------------------|--------------------|------------|----------------|
|        1 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | Received 10 from supplier |      1 |  10 | Chicken |                3 |                  6 |          8 |             12 |
|        2 | January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |  Received 5 from supplier |      2 |   5 |    Beef |                5 |             (null) |          9 |         (null) |
|        4 | January, 11 2015 00:00:00 |  Received 5 from supplier |      1 |   5 | Chicken |                6 |             (null) |          2 |         (null) |
```